# Как прописать .htaccess так, что бы редиректило на главную страницу?

Tags: php, html

как правильно прописать в .htaccess, чтоб при переходе на другие страницы, например www.magaz/catalog редиректило на главную?

Answer (score 0):

что-то вроде такого

```
RewriteRule . / [R=303,L]
```

или 307.

Comment: на локалке получается, но на сайте все равно не редиректит

Comment: @oleg выясняйте в чем там разница у вас на сайте и локалке